# Review my token? Everything 'seems' to work on the testnet. Any issues?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, tokens

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;


contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}
contract Token {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}


/*  ERC 20 token */
contract StandardToken is Token {

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
      if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
      if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
      return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
}


/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
 contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}


/**
 * @title Basic token
 * @dev Basic version of StandardToken, with no allowances. 
 */
contract Token1 is StandardToken, owned{
  using SafeMath for uint256;
// metadata
    string public constant name = "Basic Attention Token";
    string public constant symbol = "BAT";
    uint256 public constant decimals = 18;
    string public version = "1.0";



    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* This notifies clients about the amount burnt */
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
   function Token1(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    uint8 decimalUnits,
    string tokenSymbol,
    address centralMinter
    ) {
    if(centralMinter != 0 ) owner = centralMinter; 
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply

    }


    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /* Approve and then communicate the approved contract in a single tx */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }        

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                                // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;     // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                           // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                             // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                      // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                                // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }
function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner {
    balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
    totalSupply += mintedAmount;
    Transfer(0, owner, mintedAmount);
    Transfer(owner, target, mintedAmount);
}
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                // Check if the sender has enough
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                               // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Everything 'seems' to work except for transfer()? I can't send the tokens for some reason. I'm not sure why. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

In `StandarToken` has declared

```
mapping (address => uint256) balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
```

But your contract `Token1` which inherits from `StandardToken` has this

```
/* This creates an array with all balances */
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;
```

Also you have SafeMath declared but never use it.

Comment: Do I need both? I was confused I don't know if I need both? Can I have the function in standard token and not listed at all in my token?

Comment: No, you only need one. It is happening `transfer` use the first one, and some of the others will use the second. So you end up manipulating different data.